# Serialize JSON into Ember-Data (two different models in payload)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have JSON coming from the server which looks like:

```
data: {
       user: {
              address: {
                         id: "id",
                         city: "city",
                         street: "street",
                         .......
              }
              name: "name",
              ......
       }

       authentication: {
                         token: "token",
                         id: "id"
       }
}
```

In Ember I have a model **auth** which should represent the **authentication** model that I get from the server. Since I have different names for same model on the server and in the Ember store, I wrote a serializer with one method typeForRoot(root) where I just map server **authentication** to Ember **auth**.
Problem is that this typeForRoot is actually never invoked, and I do not have a slightly idea why.

Here is Ember auth model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    token: DS.attr('string')

});
```

And here is my serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

  typeForRoot: function(root) {
    // 'authentication' should become 'auth'
    var subRoot = root.substring(0, root.length - 10);

    // _super normalizes 'authentication' to 'auth'
    return this._super(subRoot);
  }
});
```

My **user** model is being properly saved in the store (I'm using a separate, model based, serializer for user), but I get the message `WARNING: Encountered "authentication" in payload, but no model was found for model name "authentication" (resolved model name using shop-app@serializer:user:.typeForRoot("authentication"))` when **authentication** model needs to be saved in **auth** model in the store.

Does anyone know how can I overcome this problem.
Thanks,
Milan

Comment: Could you provide us with the file names?

Comment: On a side note: `_super` "normalizes" 'auth' to 'auth', in this case.

Comment: File names:
Ember auth model: auth.js
Serializer: application.js

Comment: OK, since it's the application serializer, I'd expect it to "translate" "user" to "" and which may lead to errors in their own right. What happens if you put this code in the `auth` serializer instead (i.e. rename the file)?

Comment: I have a separate serializer for user, and if I put this code from app serializer into a auth serializer, the result is the same as I describe above.

Comment: OK, it was worth a try. :-/ The user serializer get called though?

Comment: Yes, user serializer get called.

Comment: I'm out of guesses. :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Ember-Data handle two models from one JSON payload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607845/can-ember-data-handle-two-models-from-one-json-payload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `typeForRoot` you've implemented is on the auth serialiser?  If you notice the error, it states:

`shop-app@serializer:user:.typeForRoot("authentication")`

This particularly points to the User serialiser.

I assume you're doing a request for the User model which returns the User model and Auth model in the data - since your using the User adapter and Serialiser to do this, you would need to implement the `typeForRoot` logic on the User serialiser.

Comment: I moved away from ember-data. Thanks foe helping.