# Can Ember-Data handle two models from one JSON payload?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have JSON coming from the server which looks like:

```
data: {
       user: {
              address: {
                         id: "id",
                         city: "city",
                         street: "street",
                         .......
              }
              name: "name",
              ......
       }

       authentication-token: {
                         token: "token",
                         id: "id"
       }
}
```

The idea is to store this two models (user, authentication-token) in ember store under the same names. When I gat the above mentioned response from a server, model user is saved successfully, but model authentication-token does not get saved to the store at all. When I log the data (in the adapter) before the data is passed to serializer I see that JSON has a structure which Ember-Data expects. I don't know whether the problem is that Ember-Data cannot handle two models in success at one time, and then save it to the corresponding models, or something else. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604167/serialize-json-into-ember-data-two-different-models-in-payload) all makes sense to me. Of course, this was the problem in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604167/serialize-json-into-ember-data-two-different-models-in-payload). Anyway, ember-data's RESTAdapter can't handle this. If you're requesting a singular resource `user` it expects at most this user as a singular answer. Any other resource that may be "side-loaded" has to be an array. The requested singular `user` can either be a record under the `user` key or the first entry in an array unter the `users` key. Everything else (except meta data) has to be plural.

In case you're requesting a plural resource `users`, the main response must be under the `users` key, any sideloaded users that aren't part of the response prfixed with `_` under the `_users` key.

For your example all this means that your json must be formatted like this:

```
data: {
       user: {
              address: {
                         id: "id",
                         city: "city",
                         street: "street",
                         .......
              }
              name: "name",
              ......
       }

       authentication-tokens: [{
                         token: "token",
                         id: "id"
       }]
}
```

If you can't change your server, you'd have to configure the RESTAdapter to normalize the JSON data through [normalize](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize) of the Serializer.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I did not tried yet, but your post is very helpful. I'll try your solution this days and I'll let you know does it work. By the way, i think that the right way to normalize the payload is through **[normalize](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize).**

Comment: You're right. In this case you have to use normalize, normalizePayload would be too late. I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I moved away from ember-data. Thanks for helping.